# how can pass a variable in redirect?

Tags: templating, redirect

```
1.{% set workTitle = craft.request.getLastSegment()  %}
2.{% if currentUser %}
3.     {{workTitle}}
4.{% else %}
5.  {% redirect "/visit/index?artwork=workTitle" %}
6.{% endif %}
```

Each line of code are working fine except the line 5. I set a value on line 1. Line 3 returns the set value but on line 5 when am trying to redirect it doesn't return correct path.
Redirect returns the below path instead of the returning the set value of workTitle.

**http://abc.dev/visit/index?artwork=workTitle**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think:

```
{% redirect "/visit/index?artwork="~workTitle %}
```

Comment: Beat me to it

Comment: Apparently not. @SelvinOrtiz I think you had me by 3-4 seconds. Might want to add the initial "{" to your code.

Comment: And you took the time to explain what you were doing, mine was a limp "I think". Sad.

Answer (score 5):

Update line 5 to **concatenate** the path/URL with the variable **workTitle**.

`{% redirect "/visit/index?artwork=" ~ workTitle %}`

Comment: FWIW: You can also interpolate the variable, like this: `{% redirect "/visit/index?artwork=#{workTitle}" %}`. This syntax might be preferable if you have many variables to include in the query params.

Comment: Also… the `url` Twig helper might come in handy! `{% redirect url('/visit/index', { artwork: workTitle }) %}`. The added benefit here is that it discards null values, and keeps your URLs nice and trim.